# Efficient way to create a numpy boolean array from an array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to convert a numpy array

```
 np.array([1,3,2])
```

to

```
 np.array([[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]])
```

Any idea of how to do this efficiently?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an bool array, and then fill it:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1])
b = np.zeros((len(a), a.max() + 1), bool)
b[np.arange(len(a)), a] = 1
```

Comment: This should be the fastest for all but the smallest operands.

Answer (score 0):

Try pandas's get dummy method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1 ,3, 2])
df = pd.get_dummies(arr)
```

if what you need is numpy array object, do:

```
arr2 = df.values
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to just select the right values from `np.eye` or the identity matrix:

```
a =  np.array([1,3,2]) 
b = np.eye(max(a))[a-1]
```

This would probably be the most straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare to `[1, 2, 3]` like so:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,3,2]) 
>>> np.equal.outer(a, np.arange(1, 4)).view(np.int8)
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

or equivalent but slightly faster

```
>>> (a[:, None] == np.arange(1, 4)).view(np.int8)
```